# Dnsmasq cache dump

Tags: linux, cache, dnsmasq

How to dump the cache of `dnsmasq`?

This,

**How to see dnsmasq cache contents**
https://www.snbforums.com/threads/how-to-see-dnsmasq-cache-contents.36478/

says

> sent SIGUSR1 to dump the cache to syslog

I followed it, but get only very few entries. In fact almost all of them are my local settings which is not what I'm after.

So, how to dump the cache of `dnsmasq`?

Answer (score 5):

SIGUSR1 works for me, but you must have **log-queries** parameter enabled in *dnsmasq* configuration.

Comment: While this may answer the question, it would be a better answer if you could provide some explanation for **how** to enable log queries.

Comment: *How* to enable log queries was not the original question.  But to answer it, *log-queries* is the name of configuration parameter of dnsmasq, there's an example in /etc/dnsmasq.conf, though I'm not sure if the path of this configuration file can be different based on distribution the OP is using.

Comment: That should be in your answer not a comment.

Comment: Not sure if that's better now.